# Which questions should one read on stackoverflow? (regarding C++)

Tags: c++

Since I'm still learning c++ (and with still I mean since 5 years :-) ) I thought, what better way to learn the hidden details than asking for it.

So, I'm not looking for the question with the most votes, but I would like to know, if you have ever read an article here, you think every intermediate c++ programmer should read to gain a bettter understanding of the craft.

Comment: a better way is to code. And if you run into trouble ask at StackOverflow. :) And if you already read the c++faq you should be all set, that is where the most asked questions end up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant suggest you an article but I can advice you two amazing books by Scott Meyers ( I hope they help you). I never seen anything better.

[More Effective C++: 35 New Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)
[Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)

Answer (score 3):

I would say the **c++-faq** tag is probably a good suggestion.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq

Comment: already read the interesting posts (three pages deep).